# Obtain Apple ID from son/daughter for tracking app

Tags: iphone, apple-id, password

I have signed up for TeenSafe to monitor the content of my 15 year old's usage of her text/pic messages on her iPhone (I suspect sexting and explicit pictures).  In order to establish the link, it says that I need her apple ID and password.  I don't want her to know that I am going to be monitoring it, and she says I have no reason for her to give it to me.  Apple will not release that information to me.  Is there a way for me as a parent (and the person paying the bill) to get it?

Comment: I've deleted a few comments that were about parenting and not related to the core issue of how a parent can or can't obtain the password to a child's iCloud account. Please keep comments to improving the clarity of the question technically.

Comment: Laurissa, If you want to edit the question to explain what feature(s) of TeenSafe you are most interested in, people might be able to suggest alternative tools that don't need the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple is cracking down on all services that use an iCloud password and going forward, even knowing your child's password won't let you use it with a third party service.

The person controlling the Apple ID will have to issue an application specific password which will clearly be shown if your child ever logs in to check on his or her account.

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6186

Furthermore, if your child changes their password, you would then be locked out as all application specific passwords are revoked upon a password change.

In short, you have three viable options:

- compel your child to self-disclose the password
- take control of the account directly
- install a key logger on a computer they use and hope to capture the iCloud password and then hope they don't change it once you have it.

You might be able to track things for a short while before Apple stops supporting non-app specific passwords, but you'll want to check with whatever service you use for monitoring that they are ready for Apple's increased security relating to iCloud and unauthorized access to an account.

Comment: ... or set it all up on a Family Sharing account?

Comment: @Tetsujin Great Suggestion! With Family Sharing, people listed as "adults" can opt out of the location sharing. I wonder if people set up as children are prevented from opting out of location sharing. Also, it doesn't really log chat messages, but that might work with parental controls on the device...

Comment: prevented from opt-out, very likely; though it might be Catch 22 getting them to opt-in initially.